# Why substring cannot be found in the target string?

Tags: python-3.x, str-replace

To understand the values of each variable, I improved a script for replacement from Udacity class. I convert the codes in a function into regular codes. However, my codes do not work while the codes in the function do. I appreciate it if anyone can explain it. Please pay more attention to function "tokenize".

Below codes are from Udacity class (CopyRight belongs to Udacity).

```
# download necessary NLTK data
import nltk
nltk.download(['punkt', 'wordnet'])

# import statements
import re
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

url_regex = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'


def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('corporate_messaging.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    df = df[(df["category:confidence"] == 1) & (df['category'] != 'Exclude')]
    X = df.text.values
    y = df.category.values
    return X, y


def tokenize(text):
    detected_urls = re.findall(url_regex, text)  # here, "detected_urls" is a list for sure
    for url in detected_urls:
        text = text.replace(url, "urlplaceholder") # I do not understand why it can work while does not work in my code if I do not convert it to string

    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    clean_tokens = []
    for tok in tokens:
        clean_tok = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok).lower().strip()
        clean_tokens.append(clean_tok)

    return clean_tokens


X, y = load_data()
for message in X[:5]:
    tokens = tokenize(message)
    print(message)
    print(tokens, '\n')
```

Below is its output:
[image]

I want to understand the variables' values in function "tokenize()". Following are my codes.

```
X, y = load_data()
detected_urls =  []
for message in X[:5]:
    detected_url = re.findall(url_regex, message)
    detected_urls.append(detected_url)
print("detected_urs: ",detected_urls)    #output a list without problems

# replace each url in text string with placeholder
i = 0
for url in detected_urls:
    text = X[i].strip()
    i += 1
    print("LN1.url= ",url,"\ttext= ",text,"\n type(text)=",type(text))
    url = str(url).strip()  #if I do not convert it to string, it is a list. It does not work in text.replace() below, but works in above function.
    if url in text:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")    #always show no
    text = text.replace(url, "urlplaceholder")
    print("\nLN2.url=",url,"\ttext= ",text,"\n type(text)=",type(text),"\n===============\n\n")
```

The output is shown below.

[image]

The outputs for "LN1" and "LN2" are same. The "if" condition always output "no". I do not understand why it happens.

Any further help and advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Inside the 2nd `for` loop can you please print `text` and `url` which is 1 line above the `if` statement?

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski, Thanks! I added the outputs into the original questions. Please review them. Thanks again!

Comment: @Leon you were meant to add them as text, not as an image …

Comment: @Programmer, my apologies.

Comment: @Leon please remove the images from your post, and, instead, put the output there as text …

Comment: @Programmer, there is urls in the text. The system does not accept them.

Comment: @Leon which system does not accept urls ?

Comment: @Programmer, I use Windows 10 pro. The browser is Google Chrome. Your website (system) does not accept urls if I list the output in code bracket. I did this to make the poster look nice.